Separate funnels that are MECE in Mixpanel
I'm newer to mixpanel and haven't been able to find an answer. I'm building a funnel to track conversions. The events are in this order:

Homepage opened
Clicked to open catalog
Catalog page opened
Checkout page opened
Clicked to complete order

I want to build 2 funnels:

A) one funnel with all 5 steps
B) but I also want to build a funnel with only steps 3-5, because some people might navigate to the catalog page directly in their URL

To make the funnels MECE, then I'm trying to figure out if I can add filters, so specifically:

For funnel (A) I'd want to ensure that steps 3-5 FOLLOWED step 2, i.e., that this user definitely started on homepage
For funnel (B) I'd want to ensure that steps 3-5 did NOT happen after a step 2, i.e., that step 3 was the true "start" of the process

How can I do this?
Also as a new user, TOTALLY open to feedback if this is a horrible idea for known reasons
